# How to get a variable value of a post in django models ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created two models one for the post and another for comments. I want to get the title of the post in **str** by querying forginKey variable in Comments class
is it even possible?

i've tried using `Comment._meta.get_field('post_id')` but it wont works and I gets this error

```
Exception Value:    
must be str, not ForeignKey
```

My Models :

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/posts", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post_id = models.ForeignKey("post.Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " in post: " + Comment._meta.get_field('post_id')
```

I want to get the value of title for every comment posted on site to show in Django admin.

Comment: Not sure why you would do that. A foreign key field is no different from any other field; you would access it via self just like you do with the name.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
class Post(Model):
    title = CharField(...)

class Comment(Model):
    post_id = ForeignKey(Post, ...)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} in post: {}".format(self.name, self.post_id.title)
```

And by the way, foreign keys are not usually named ending with `_id`, since it evokes that the field just holds the integer with id of the object, which is not the case: a fully-fledged `Post` object can be accessed.

Comment: I tried that first time exactly like you and I get this error message `no such column: post_post.name`

Comment: This *must* work...could you please edit your post and include the whole `Post` and `Comment` model classes, without the `...`?

Comment: Ah, my bad, you call it title and not name, I am sorry...see the edit :)

Comment: I see your mistake variable name and I change my title to name then wrote the exact code you write :) but it wont work. the name is a variable in my Comment class and title is a variable inside Post class! I just want to get post title
+ I used `Post.title` and get this value in django admin :
`<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002670FA0DF60>`

Comment: `Post.title` will not do what you want, as you are accessing the attribute statically. Anyway `self.post_id` returns an instance of `Post` object which has a name, so you are able to access it via `self.post_id.title`. And if not, please show me the exception you get.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you solve the problem, please consider accepting it so the others can immediately see what to do when they run into the same problem.